# Expected number of cycles in permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

Consider a random permutation of $1,2,\ldots,n$. What is the expected number of cycles in it? I thought about using linearity of expectation, but here it's not clear how we can break down the main random variable into different ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple argument shows that the expected number of fixed points (cycles of length 1) of a random permutation is $1$: Let $p_i$ be the number of permutations that fix position $i$.  Clearly there are $(n-1)!$ of these.  Thus all the permutations together have a total of $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = n\cdot(n-1)!$ fixed points, and the average permutation has $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{n!} = 1$ fixed points.

A generalization of this argument shows that the expected number of cycles of length $k$ is $\frac1k$.

For example, the expected number of cycles of a random permutation of order 3 is $$1 + \frac12 + \frac 13 = \frac{11}6$$

and you can easily verify this by a  hand count: There are $2$ permutations of type $(a\,b\,c)$ with one cycle, $3$ permutations of type $(a)(b\,c)$ with two cycles, and $1$ permutation of type $(a)(b)(c)$ with three cycles, for a total of  $2\cdot 1 + 3\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3 = 11$ cycles for all six permutations.

The numerators are closely related to the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Here's my attempt at counting the expected number of 3-cycle: https://imgur.com/18AqiA1 . Following your suggestion and this method, I can also derive other expected numbers. But I still feel this is a bit too complicated, since I had to jump between the word representation (when collecting the elements of the expression) and the cycle representation (when reasoning about the triple-counting). Did I over-complicate things?

Answer (score 8):

The combinatorial class equation of permutations with  cycles marked is
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This translates to the mixed (EGF/OGF) bivariate generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$
Differentiate with respect to $u$
$$\frac{d}{du} G(z, u) = 
\exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\log\frac{1}{1-z}$$
and set $u=1$ to obtain the OGF of the expected number of cycles
$$Q(z) = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\log\frac{1}{1-z}
= \frac{1}{1-z}\log\frac{1}{1-z}.$$
Extracting coefficients we finally obtain
$$[z^n] Q(z) = \sum_{p=1}^n [z^p] \log\frac{1}{1-z}
= \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{1}{p} = H_n.$$

**Remark.** Differentiating and setting $u=1$ turns $m \times u^k z^n/n!$ into $m \times k z^n/n!$ where $m$ counts the number of permutations of $n$ elements having $k$ cycles, i.e. $m=\left[n\atop k\right].$