# Average length of a cycle in a n-permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> What is the average length of a cycle in a permutation of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: do you count cycles of length $1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: The expected number of $k$-cycles in a random permutation of $[n]$ [is $\frac1k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/973437/12042). Thus, the expected number of cycles in a random permutation of $[n]$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=H_n$, the $n$-th harmonic number.

- How many cycles are there altogether in all permutations of $[n]$?
- What is the total length of all of these cycles?
- What is their mean length?

Comment: Thanks Brian! Please let me know if my further analysis is incorrect. Total number of k-cycles (in all permutations) is $n!/k$ and total number of cycles (in all permutations) is $n! \cdot H_n$. Hence, $p(length=k \mid cycle)$ (probability that a random cycle has length k) is $\frac{n!/k}{n! \cdot H_n}=\frac{1}{k \cdot H_n}$. From here, avg cycle length=$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot p(length=k | cycle)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot \frac{1}{k\cdot H_n}=\frac{n}{H_n}$

Comment: @talegari: You're welcome! I had in mind a slightly different calculation, but yours works too. (I was calculating the total length of all cycles as $n\cdot n!$ and dividing by $n!H_n$.)

Comment: @brian-m-scott : It would be great to hear about the approach you had on mind.

Comment: Proof of the fact: **The expected number of k-cycles in a random permutation of $[n]$ is $\frac{1}{k}$**. Let $x_i=1$ if $i$ is a part of a k-cycle, else 0. $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{k}$ counts the number of k-cycles of $[n]$. We have $E \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{k} \right)=\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n}E(x_i)=\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{k}$

Proof of the fact: **Probability that 1 belongs to a k-cycle is 1/n (independent of k)**. Apart from one, a k-cycle can be constructed in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!$ . Dividing by $n!$ gives $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 6):

By  way   of  enrichment  here  is  an   alternate  formulation  using
combinatorial   classes as defined by Flajolet and Sedgewick. The  class  of   permutations   with cycle length marked is

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}^2\times\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}^3\times\textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}^4\times\textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = 
\exp\left(uz + u^2\frac{z^2}{2} +
u^3\frac{z^3}{3} +
u^4\frac{z^4}{4} +
u^5\frac{z^5}{5} + \cdots\right)$$
which is
$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-uz}\right)
= \frac{1}{1-uz}.$$

As this is an EGF to get the OGF of the total cycle length
in all permutations we must compute
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u}
G(z, u)\right|_{u=1}.$$

This is
$$\left. (-1) \times
\frac{1}{(1-uz)^{2}} \times (-z)\right|_{u=1}
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^{2}}.$$

This yields
$$n! [z^n] \frac{z}{(1-z)^{2}} = n! \times n.$$

This  could have  been obtained  trivially  by noting  that the  cycle
lengths  in   each  permutation  sum   to  $n$  and  there   are  $n!$
permutations.

On the other hand the   class  of   permutations   with
cycle count marked is

$$\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots)$$

This gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = 
\exp\left(uz + u\frac{z^2}{2} +
u\frac{z^3}{3} +
u\frac{z^4}{4} +
u\frac{z^5}{5} + \cdots\right)$$
which is

$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

Proceding as before to get the total number of cycles we obtain
$$\left. \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\log\frac{1}{1-z} \right|_{u=1}
= \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

This gives
$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}
= n! H_n.$$

It follows that the average is
$$\frac{n}{H_n} \sim \frac{n}{\log n}.$$

The following Maple program shows  how to compute this statistic using
the cycle index $Z(S_n)$ of the symmetric group.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


v :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local part, src, idx, totcyc;

    totcyc := 0; 

    if n=1 then
        idx := [a[1]];
    else
        idx := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    for part in idx do
        totcyc := totcyc + 
        lcoeff(part)*degree(part);
    od;

    n/totcyc;
end;
```

We get the sequence
$$1,4/3,{\frac {18}{11}},{\frac {48}{25}},{\frac {300}{137}},
{\frac {120}{49}},{\frac {980}{363}},{\frac {2240}{761}},\ldots$$